# How do these restrictions on the wavefunction logically arise?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

My lecturer notes that the following restrictions on the wavefunction (in addition to it being a solution to the Schrodinger equation) are logical:

i) Continuous (mathematical definition of a continuous function)

ii) Single-valued (every x input has precisely one y output)

iii) Have a continuous derivative i.e. can define the gradient at every point

Why are these restrictions necessary?

Comment: Hi, if you add some of your own thoughts to why these requirements for the wavefunctions arise, people are more inclined to help you understand in detail why.

Comment: Well, the second one is not a restriction at all, since all functions are single-valued. Also, $\psi$ has to be continuous (and moreover, even _differentiable_) so as to be a solution of a differential equation. As for the third restriction, it is simply not there. For example, a particle in an infinite potential box violates it.

Comment: In case (ii) it means that wavefunctions cannot have a form such as $y=\sin^{-1}(x)$ which has repeated values for $|x|\le 1$. (i) means that an infinitesimal change about a point must not cause a big change in its value, such as happens in a step function.

Comment: The simple answer is that you will use this function to calculate eigenvalues/expectation values of operators, and you would have difficulty to define those for functions that cannot do I - III. Note, sometimes we use functions that are not smooth at every point (eg particle in a box).

Comment: @IvanNeretin the nonphysical infinite potential in that case makes the third condition impossible (or at least only gives the trivial solution), but it should hold under realistic physical conditions.

Comment: @Tyberius Well, if we stick to the realistic physical conditions, then pretty much all functions have continuous derivatives.